# How to use a Time format in Android

Tags: java, android, andengine

I am trying to take have a time that counts down all the way to 0 from 1 minute.

I have already created my timer. I just need to know how do i convert a int such as 100 to a String to show 1:00 as in a minute and keep counting down like minus 1 secodn from the int and convert it to the String :59?

Any suggestions?

Comment: what is "100" in your case? 100 seconds? you're saying you want to convert 100 to 1:00 but 100 would convert to 1:40 (1m40s). Are you asking how to convert 100 seconds into minutes and seconds as a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you simply want to divide your number by 60 to get the minutes and then mod your number by 60 to get the seconds and then concat the strings.

```
int remainingTime = 100;// or whatever number of seconds you have left
String min = (remainingTime / 60) + "";
String sec = (remainingTime % 60) + "";

String remainingTimeStamp = "min" + ":" + "sec";
```

If you want to get fancy with it, check to see if min and sec are less than 10 and append a leading zero, so that it looks like 01:05 rather than 1:5

I'm not sure what you mean by "I already have my timer".  I'll wait for you to update your question, rather than speculate as to what you might mean, before I continue elaborating.

Comment: So how would i append the 0 if it is less than 10? Could you put an edit?

Comment: Even better:
  
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss");
String formatted = df.format(remainingTime * 1000);

Comment: @coder_for_life, Steven's answer is the more efficient one, if in fact this is what you're trying to do. I gave you the more verbose answer because I wasn't even sure what you were actually trying to accomplish. And dude, no offense but if you need help figuring out how to add a leading "0" to a string based on if a number is less than 10, then I have grave doubts about your stated assertion that you've got the Timer worked out.  Are you running it in a Thread (as you absolutely should be?), if not, and it's in your UI thread, then you're in for some very nasty results.

Comment: Of course it is running on a thread! And am familiar with appending. Using StringBuffer. As i am not familier with appending a 0 in front of the 5 to show 1:05 instead of 1:5  for a minute and 5 seconds. Yeah i built the timer. I am using andengine to build a game. I have my timer that basically controls the speed, timer and environment. It runs by seconds as a float.

Answer (score 1):

- Edit:
  Since it appears you were looking for formatting 100 seconds here is it formatted:

  ```
  SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss");
  String formatted = df.format(remainingTime * 1000);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

To add to this, check the http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html class. Note that this is not in 'org.apache' which has another DateUtils class.